# Pros and Cons of developing .Net Solutions in Vista instead of XP

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-vista

i am changing my hardware which currently runs Win XP and i am wondering if i should also upgrade my OS to vista. so my question is,  what are the most common issues/advantages you find while developing in VS2008 on Vista. with out taking into consideration WPF. should i keep XP where i have no Problems? or what version of vista best fit developer needs?

Comment: WPF is not a concern relative to XP/Vista as WPF is not platform specific. It works on both Vista or XP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used both Vista and XP before as a developer machine.

But **Windows Server 2008** is the smoothest of them all. Super stable, pretty as Vista and fast as XP. And you can install products that need server (BitTalk, SQL Server Standard, Sharepoint,...)

Be sure to check out [Convert your Windows Server 2008 to a Workstation!](http://www.win2008workstation.com/wordpress/) web page for tips how to configure Server 2008 to feel and behave more as a desktop machine. There is even a tool called [Windows Server 2008 Workstation Converter](http://www.win2008workstation.com/wordpress/2008/07/17/windows-server-2008-workstation-converter/).

Drivers should be a problem, since it shares kernel with Vista and you can use those. I have use 32 bit ones and 64 bit ones with any hiccups.

Of course, VS2008 runs without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I develop fulltime on Windows XP, and at home on Vista 64. Other than the 32-bit limitation on Memory, I have noticed no tangible benefit/problems with developing on either platform.

Answer (score 1):

UAC on vista can cause some issues for you but they are minimal with vs2008.  And for the most part you can run the application as admin to get around them when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have Vista SP1 and VS2008 SP1 and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I have Vista Home Prem and it's fine for .NET development.

As the post above says, UAC does cause issues. For example, you can't save in certain dirs with VS2008 unless you right click the program icon and run as an admin. This is what I do, and problem is solved (I am admin on the machine too).

Also, you will have problems with apps that have databases as you may have to run as admin to connect to the db.